# Matching ranges of lines in python (like sed ranges)

Tags: python, sed

Sometimes the good old tools still work best. In sed, I could write things like this:

```
sed '/^Page 5:/,/^Page 6:/p' 
sed '110,/^Page 10:/+3p'
sed '/^Page 5:/,/^Page 6:/s/this/that/g'
```

The first applies a substitution to all lines between the ones matching /^Page 5:/ and /^Page 6:/. The second starts printing at line 110 and stops 3 lines after the one matching /^Page 10:/. The third example applies a substitution to each line in the specified range.

I don't mind using re.search to search line by line, but for line ranges, line numbers or relative offsets, I end up having to write a whole parser. Is there a python idiom or module that can simplify this kind of operations?

I don't want to call sed from python: I'm doing python-type things with text, and just want to be able to operate on line ranges in a straightforward way.

**Edit:** It's fine if the solution works on a python list of strings. I'm not looking to process gigabytes of text. But I do need to specify several operations, not just one, and interleave them with single-line regexp substitutions. I've looked at iterators (in fact I would welcome a solution using iterators), but the results always got out of hand for anything more than single operation.

Here's a simple example: A snippet of code with java-style comments, to be changed to python comments. (Don't worry I am NOT trying to write a cross-compiler using regexps :-)

```
/* 
 This is a multi-line comment.
 It does not obligingly start lines with " * "
 */

x++;  // a single-line comment
```

It's trivial to write regexps that change "//" comments to "#" (and also to drop semicolons, change "++" to "+= 1", etc.) But how do we insert "#" at the start of each line of a multi-line java comment? I can do it with a regexp on the entire file as a single string, which is a pain because the rest of the transformations are line-oriented. I've also been unable to (usefully) integrate iterators with line-oriented regexps. I'd appreciate suggestions.

Comment: "end up having to write a whole parser"?  Just to count lines?  Why?

Comment: "But how do we insert "#" at the start of each line of a multi-line java comment?"  That's a far, far more complex question.  Unrelated to the title of the question and the first part of the question.  If this is what you **really** want to know then ask the **real** question separately.

Comment: @S, my original question said "I'm doing python-type things with text, and just want to be able to operate on line ranges in a straightforward way." I want to match line ranges in order to do something with them, not just to print them out. This my first SO question and I'm learning a lot about how to keep the wrong parts from getting all the attention.

Comment: "my original question said ..." doesn't matter much.  If it was too subtle, then simply close it or ask another question.  There's no limit or quota.  Feel free to ask your **real** question separately rather than argue that an somewhat ambiguous question was really better than it appeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to use the regex flags `re.DOTALL` or `re.MULTILINE`.

The first treats newlines as regular characters, so if you use `.*` it might count newlines inside the pattern.

The second is almost the same, but you can still use linestarts (`^`) and endlines (`$`) to match these. This can be useful to count lines.

I could, for now, come up with this, which prints ONE MORE LINE after the ocurrence of "six" (a whole line is captured by the final `^.*?$`, but I'm pretty sure there should be a much better way):

```
import re

source = """one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
ten"""

print re.search('^three.*six.*?^.*?$', source, re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE).group(0)
```

Comment: Of the answers offered, this seems like the most suitable approach for applying a bunch of transformations to a file. It's a pain to integrate it with line-oriented regexps, though, so I'd still like to hear of a better way...

Comment: I think the line-oriented regexes are a kind of wizardry way above my abilities. But for sure there must be a way. I guess...

Comment: Didn't mean anything fancy by line-oriented: Just looping through the document line by line and doing simple replacements within a single line. Traditional regexp usage, in other words. I'm sure you're well on top of that!

Comment: @alexis well, if you meant "mastering regexes" in the broad way, I'd say go for it. It's not that hard if you get a good simple book, and after you get it, life changes forever. For the better, of course.

Answer (score 1):

For the comments at least, just use a real parser.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from pyparsing import javaStyleComment
import re

text = """

/*
 * foo
 * bar
 * blah
 */

/***********************
 it never ends
***********************/

/* foo

   bar blah
*/

/*
* ugly
* comment
*/

// Yet another

int a = 100;

char* foo;

"""

commentTokenStripper = re.compile(r'\s*[/\\\*]')

for match in javaStyleComment.scanString(text):
    start,end = match[-2:]
    print '# comment block %d-%d ##############' % (start,end)
    lines = ['#' + re.sub(commentTokenStripper, '', l) for l in match[0][0].splitlines()]
    print '\n'.join(lines)
    print
```

Yields

```
# comment block 2-30 ##############
#
# foo
# bar
# blah
#

# comment block 32-96 ##############
#
# it never ends
#

# comment block 98-121 ##############
# foo
# 
#   bar blah
#

# comment block 123-145 ##############
#
# ugly
# comment
#

# comment block 147-161 ##############
# Yet another
```

Comment: `sed` ranges are *a lot* more flexible than just specifying line numbers. See the OP's examples as a starting point.

Comment: That's right. Slice notation is great for absolute line numbers, but I'm asking about the rest.

Comment: Thanks, that's the kind of thing I end up doing when I need to mix in multi-line expressions. But chunking into groups based on a pattern is only one of the things I need this for.

Comment: Incidentally, there's an easier way to break up the file into page units: read it as one string with `text = open(filename).read()`, then just do `pages = re.split(r"\nPage\d+\n", text)`

Comment: Updated answer to better handle the specific use case.

Comment: Thanks! +1 for pyparsing. If I can't avoid writing a parser, at least I can have some help...

Comment: If you're going to parse source code, do it for real. Regexs are fine and dandy until you scan something that has comment tokens in a quoted string. :p There's lots of neat stuff going on with llvm with this problem in mind. Alternatively, you could use gcc and dump RTL like http://www.gson.org/egypt/ does. Then parsing becomes much easier.

Comment: I don't need a full-blown parser, this is for lightweight (even throwaway) scripts. Converting simple markdown-style formats, that kind of thing. 95% of the time a simple loop on readline() and a few regexps are enough, but the other 5% introduces a lot of scaffolding when all I need is just a bit of state dependence.

Comment: @alexis: "Converting simple markdown-style formats" is unrelated to Java comment location and unrelated to SED-style matching rules.  Please help us by having a focus on one **real** question.  It appears that you have three separate questions going on here.

Comment: @S, I don't need help with a specific transformation. I can throw messy code at any of these just fine. My question, from the beginning, was about a clean approach to a class of tasks: Dealing with ranges while processing text line by line. I gave a comparable example (sed) and some use cases. If there's a better way to phrase the question, please suggest it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
import re

def firstline(rx, lst):
    for n, s in enumerate(lst):
        if re.search(rx, s):
            return n
    return 0
```

and then:

```
text = ["How", "razorback", "jumping", "frogs", "can", "level", "six", "piqued", "gymnasts"]

# prints all lines between the one matching `^r` and the one matching `^s`
print text[firstline('^r', text)+1:firstline('^s', text)]
```

This looks overly verbose, but the verbosity can be reduced, for example:

```
import functools
L = functools.partial(firstline, lst=text)

print text[L('^r')+1:L('^s')]
```

The latter is almost as concise  as its sed counterpart.

Comment: This looks promising, thanks! But when these ranges match multiple times, pattern2 should find the first match after pattern1. (I know, I didn't spell this out in the question). This code will only find the first match for each pattern, regardless of order.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a straightforward way to do that in Python.

But there are different approaches you could follow:

- Read the file line by line and activate your search only when you need.
  *This has the advantage of read the file only one time, but it works on one line at the time.*
- Slice the file with [`itertools.islice()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) and do the search of your pattern there.
  *You'll have to read the file again for each patterns, but it's very easy to implement.*
- Use [`mmap`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/mmap.html).
  *If your file is not too big and you have more than one pattern to look for, I'd go with this one.*

**Edit:** If you're interested in iterator tools, [`itertools.takewhile()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) with a smart lambda might do the work.

**Disclaimer:** I don't know nothing about `sed`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I'm not talking about gigabytes, so a solution that works for a list of strings would be great. I suspect there are tangles of iterators that can do that kind of thing, and make coffee while they're at it. I hope someone here comes up with a clean approach.

Comment: @alexis: I fear that the *"I hope someone here comes up with a clean approach"* will not get you very far, expecially here on SO. Anyway I've updated my answer with a reference to `itertools.takewhile()`.

Comment: Thanks, Rik. I'm not trying to be lazy, it's just that I know about iterators (including takewhile) and I find them very unwieldy for this kind of task. I admit I have little experience with using the fancy ones, which is why I'm asking for more specific guidance. I've clarified the question to hopefully make my goals clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
from __future__ import print_function

def get_lines( some_file, start_rule, end_rule, process=print ):
    line_iter= enumerate( source )
    for n, text in line_iter:
        if start_rule( n, text ): 
            process( text )
            break
    for n, text in line_iter:
        process( text )
        if end_rule( n, text ): break
```

Then you can define a lot of smaller functions:

```
def match_page_5( n, text ):
    return re.match( '^Page 5:', text )
def match_line( n, text ):
    return line == n
```

Or stateful, callable objects

```
class Match_Pattern( collections.Callable ):
    def __init__( self, pattern ):
        self.pat= re.compile( pattern )
    def __call__( self, n, text ):
        return self.pat.match( text )

class Match_Lines_Post_Pattern( collections.Callable ):
    def __init__( self, pattern, lines ):
        self.pat= re.compile( pattern )
        self.lines= lines
        self.saw_it= None
    def __call__( self, n, text ):
        if self.saw_it:
            if n == self.saw_it + self.lines
                return True
            if self.pat.match( text ):
                self.saw_it = n
```

You can create syntactic sugar via functions like this.

```
def sed_by_pattern( filename, pattern1, pattern2 ):
    with open(filename,'r') as source:
        get_lines( source, lambda n,tx: re.match(pattern1,tx), lambda n,tx: re.match(pattern2,tx) )
```

This gets you to a function like the following
This usage is  as simple as the SED command with extra punctuation.

```
sed_by_pattern( some_file, '^Page 5:', '^Page 6:' )
```

Or this bit of sugar...

```
def sed_by_matcher( filename, matcher1, matcher2 )
    with open(filename, 'r') as source:
        get_lines( source, matcher1, matcher2 )
```

This usage is  as simple as the SED command with extra punctuation.

```
see_by_matcher( some_file, match_line(100), Match_Lines_Post_Pattern( '^Page 10:', 3 ) )
```

Comment: Thanks guy but that's exactly the kind of hoops I want to avoid!

Comment: The bulk of the code is a module which you import.  It's not a hoop.  It's a version of SED written in Python.  How do you think you can avoid the complexity of SED?  It's complex.  And you're talking about some of the most complex features of SED.  Where would you like the complexity to manifest itself?  It has to be somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, @S. You are right, these are pretty powerful features of sed. But python encapsulates plenty of complex interfaces very well-- just not this one. So to answer your question, I'm hoping someone knows of a language construct, or a module I don't have to write myself, that would make my life easier.

Comment: @alexis: This module **will** make your life easier.  It's under 50 lines of code.  It does some of what you want.  It's easily extended.  I'm not sure what magical language construct you think might exist in a general-purpose programming language that matches the highly-specialized syntax of SED.  If you want more syntactic sugar you can -- easily -- create your own functions to provide whatever SED-like set of features you're looking for.